# Allowing multiple AssertionErrors before failing a test

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, chai

Is there a conventional way to attempt a group of `assert`s to always be evaluated before failing the test?

Let's say my test assesses the presence of some names on a page:

```
var pageContent = 'dummy page content';

//.include(haystack, needle, [message])
//Asserts that haystack includes needle.

assert.include(pageContent, 'Alice');
assert.include(pageContent, 'Bob');
assert.include(pageContent, 'John');
```

Now, if Alice is missing, the test would fail with a single error:

```
>AssertionError: expected 'dummy page content' to contain 'Alice'
```

However I want to be notified that *all three names* are missing since in this case failing one condition does not prevent from evaluating others.

Rather than writing a wrapper method that aggregates the would-be output of these checks and throws a single error, I was hoping there would third-party library that "specializes" in this sort of thing or perhaps in-built functionality I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 5):

I can offer two approaches.

The first one, mentioned by @Peter Lyons, relies on converting multiple assertions into a single assertion on multiple values. To keep the assertion error message useful, it's best to assert on the list of names:

```
var expected = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'John'];
var found = expected.filter(function(name) {
   return pageContent.indexOf(name) >= 0;
}

// assuming Node's require('assert')
assert.deepEqual(found, expected);
// Example error message:
// AssertionError: ["Alice","Bob","John"] deepEqual ["Alice"]
```

The second approach uses "parameterised test". I'll assume you are using BDD-style for specifying test cases in my code.

```
describe('some page', function() {
   for (var name in ['Alice', 'Bob', 'John'])
     itContainsString(name);

   function itContainsString(name) {
      it('contains "' + name + '"', function() {
        var pageContent = 'dummy page content';
        assert.include(pageContent, 'Alice');
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var found = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'John'].map(function (name) {
  return pageContent.indexOf(name) >= 0;
});
assert.include(found, true);
```

If I may opine that your desire for a wrapper library for fuzzy asserting sounds misguided. Your fuzzy rules and heuristics about what is a "soft" vs "hard" assertion failure seem like a much less sensible alternative than good old programming using the existing assertion paradigm. It's testing. It's supposed to be straightforward and easy to reason about.

Keep in mind you can always take logic such as the above and wrap it in a function called `includesOne(pageContent, needles)` so it is conveniently reusable across tests.

Comment: "Soft" assertions is exactly where I was heading, but I see your point; I guess the need for these is indicative of my tests lacking textbook atomicity. Perhaps what I'm really after is a pattern that would allow (in the example above) to create 3 separate tests from the array of inputs? I would have settled for something analogous to `includesOne`, however I can't think of a way for an assert failure to be logged as an explicit list of values missing.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to validating multiple assertions and getting feedback from all of them, regardless of which one fails first, is to use a Node.js module I wrote and published called [multi-assert](https://github.com/jamesmortensen/multi-assert). Now, before we continue, I want to point out that, in your specific use case, if you're really only asserting 3 names, then I think [Miroslav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19277109/552792) is quite sufficient. As long as it serves your needs for quickly determining what broke and what to do to fix it, then you should continue on with that solution, and there's no need for additional dependencies in your project.

But the areas where I've run into major difficulties, or needed to spend more time debugging test failures or help others do the same, is when we've asserted properties of a really large object or array. For instance, when using deepEqual, I've personally run into cases where the error message can be quite complex, confusing, and unreadable in both HTML reports as well as the logs.

With the multi-assert module, the error messages are transparently displayed and specific to what we want to measure. For example, we can do something like this:

```
// import { multiAssert } from 'multi-assert';
const { assert } = require('chai');
const { multiAssert } = require('multi-assert');

describe('Page Content Tests', () => {
  it('should contain Alice, Bob, and John somewhere in the content', () => {
    var pageContent = 'dummy page content';

    //.include(haystack, needle, [message])
    //Asserts that haystack includes needle.
  
    multiAssert([
      () => assert.include(pageContent, 'Alice'),
      () => assert.include(pageContent, 'Bob'),
      () => assert.include(pageContent, 'John')
    ]);
  });
});
```

And by running these tests, with "dummy page content", we're going to see the following error messages reported back to us with full transparency:

```
  Page Content Tests
    1) should contain Alice, Bob, and John somewhere in the content


  0 passing (7ms)
  1 failing

  1) Page Content Tests
       should contain Alice, Bob, and John somewhere in the content:
     AssertionError: 

      MultipleAssertionError: expected 'dummy page content' to include 'Alice'
        at /Users/user123/Dev/page-content-example/test/page-content.spec.js:13:20
        at /Users/user123/Dev/page-content-example/node_modules/multi-assert/src/multi-assert.js:10:13
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

      MultipleAssertionError: expected 'dummy page content' to include 'Bob'
        at /Users/user123/Dev/page-content-example/test/page-content.spec.js:14:20
        at /Users/user123/Dev/page-content-example/node_modules/multi-assert/src/multi-assert.js:10:13
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

      MultipleAssertionError: expected 'dummy page content' to include 'John'
        at /Users/user123/Dev/page-content-example/test/page-content.spec.js:15:20
        at /Users/user123/Dev/page-content-example/node_modules/multi-assert/src/multi-assert.js:10:13
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

      at multiAssert (node_modules/multi-assert/src/multi-assert.js:19:15)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/page-content.spec.js:12:5)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

I want to also note that the multi-assert module also works with other testing frameworks; it's not just limited to Mocha and Chai; however, it's worth noting that Jasmine has been evaluating soft assertions by default for quite some time due to the nature of how their test runner and assertion library are more tightly integrated. If switching to Jasmine is not an easy or desired solution, and if existing assertion methods alone don't provide the desired level of feedback, then you can see the simplicity in wrapping up existing assertions in a multiAssert function call in order to achieve this transparency in your test cases. Hoping this helps!